# How to access current node and descendants from HTML document with agility package?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack, htmldoc

I loaded the HTML into a **HTMLdocument**. Now I want to access/select each **dt** with every **dd** which belongs to the **dt** and  store it in an array for later usage. I have already tried the XPath syntax as mentioned in http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp, but it didn' work at all. I just received a `NullReferenceException`. But what do I do wrong?

Please keep in mind that sometimes there are 2 or more `**dd**` elements for one `**dt**`. I want to add every `**dd**` element to the corresponding `**dt**`.

Many thanks in advance.

```
<dl>
  <dt id="one">one</dt>
  <dd>some text</dd>
  <dt id="two">two</dt>
  <dd>some text</dd>
  <dt id="three">three</dt>
  <dd>some text</dd>
  <dd>some text</dd>
  <dt id="four">four</dt>
  <dd>some text</dd>
  and so on...
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct link between the `dt` and the `dd` elements, that's why I personally didn't find a way to provide you a solution using XPath. XSLT might be an option, however, I haven't found a quick and easy way using XSLT either.
Since you use C# I made a quick prototype-function of how this could look in C#:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dt = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();        

            using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"data.xml")){
                bool incomingDd = false;
                while(reader.Read()){
                    switch(reader.NodeType){
                        case XmlNodeType.Element:                            
                            if(String.Equals(reader.Name, "dt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){
                                dt.Add(reader.GetAttribute("id"), new List<string>());
                            }
                            else if(String.Equals(reader.Name, "dd", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){
                                incomingDd = true;                                
                            }
                            break;

                        case XmlNodeType.Text:                                
                            if(incomingDd && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Value)){                                
                                dt.Values.ElementAt(dt.Count -1).Add(reader.Value);
                                incomingDd = false;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach(var item in dt){
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} {item.Value.Count()}:");
                foreach(var dd in item.Value){
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"\t{dd}");
                }
            }
        }
```

This might not be the prettiest code to fit your needs, but this should give you an idea of how to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi codeguy, my deepest apologies for my late response, but I was busy in the last week. Many thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot!

Comment: No problem, happy to help! Could you mark it as answer if it was the solution to your problem? Thank you.